# Having issues trying to get tensorflow 2 to work with WSL 2

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow2.0, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

Using TensorFlow backend.
2021-01-09 17:01:36.009126: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'libcuda.so.1'; dlerror: libcuda.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2021-01-09 17:01:36.009169: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:313] failed call to cuInit: UNKNOWN ERROR (303)
2021-01-09 17:01:36.009212: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:156] kernel driver does not appear to be running on this host (DESKTOP-91JP32H): /proc/driver/nvidia/version does not exist
2021-01-09 17:01:36.010807: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:143] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
2021-01-09 17:01:36.058753: I tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:102] CPU Frequency: 3792000000 Hz
2021-01-09 17:01:36.059597: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x7fbb78000b20 initialized for platform Host (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2021-01-09 17:01:36.059635: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version

Here's the full error. I upgraded from WSL to WSL2 because from what I read in WSL 1 it can't locate your GPU. I went through these steps https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda/wsl with no luck.

````
from keras.layers import Dropout, Flatten, Dense, Activation, BatchNormalization
from keras.layers.convolutional import MaxPooling2D, Conv2D
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint

...

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(nb_filters1, [conv1_size, conv1_size], input_shape=(img_height, img_width , 3)))```
````

Comment: This might be a limitation of WSL, just to confirm did you convert the existing Ubuntu vm to use WSL v2 once you installed it ? You can run `wsl -l -v` from powershell to list which versions of WSL the virtual machines are running.

Comment: @Grizzle Yes I did. From what I read I thought it wasn't. Seemed like it was possible.

Comment: Please check this reference to have a proper [WSL setup](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu#wsl2_setup) in your system which might help you to solve this error.